# React: add a modal component to the root DOM

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way in react to decide the DOM parent of a component? I need to be able to add a component and it is necessary for it to reside up in the DOM tree and still be a child of an inner component.

Something along the lines of:

```
<div className="row">
    <Comp />
</div>
```

While the DOM tree would be

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="component">
...
```

The usecase is a custom modal that shows up with an overlay.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly your case is. The snippets don't really explain anything. Possibly could be solved with portals or something else. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects your case and explain your problem further. This could be XY problem.

Comment: @estus Added additional information. Seems that the portals mechanism does solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, modals are common use case for portals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic application of React's portal: it renders the selected component in the selected DOM node ( the *parent node*)

```js
render() {
  // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the children into `domNode`.
  // `domNode` is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM. ( body, a div etc etc )
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    this.props.children,
    domNode
  );
}
```